# Differential Equation with arctan

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have some troubles understanding this line in a book talking about differential equation:

$$y' = \arctan(ty)$$
$$y(0) = \alpha$$

It is written that if $\alpha = 0$, the only solution is $y = 0$

Why is that exactly?

Comment: what? $y(0)=\alpha$ is not satisfied when $y=0$

Comment: if $\alpha = 0$, then $y = 0$

Comment: called Existence and Uniqueness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This topic is usually called Existence and Uniqueness. The easier way to state the result is

If we are given $f(t,y)$ such that both $f$ and $\partial f / \partial y$ are continuous, then there is one and only one solution to $y'=f(t,y).$ Here  $\partial f / \partial y = t/(1+t^2 y^2).$ In you case, note that $y=0$ really is a solution!

Your book will have quite a bit more to say on this, usually stated using the name Lipschitz.

Comment: oh my god.. I'm really off today, what a stupid question.. yes of course, I'm sorry abot that you're right